# Can we burn Ash?

Tags: physical-chemistry, combustion

Can we burn ash at any temperature ? Will it melt ? If i am talking about ash of paper. I actually collected several samples of ashes and tried to burn it but it didn't.
Tell me wil ash change its temperature when we hest it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

To burn, a material needs to release energy when it is oxidized (absorbs oxygen*). Paper ash appears to be a mixture of CaO, SiO$_2$, Al$_2$O$_3$, MgO, SO$_3$ and Fe$_2$O$_3$ ([source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317816789_Performance_Evaluation_of_Low_Carbon_Concrete_using_Paper_Sludge_Ash/figures?lo=1)) - all oxides where the non-oxygen atoms have already acquired as much oxygen as they can.

One way of proving this is to look through the [standard enthalpies of formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation) of any compound you can make by adding extra oxygens to the above molecules, like MgO$_2$. However, you will see that they all contain more energy than the ash: there will not be any burning.

As for melting ash, that is entirely feasible. In practice it is hard: Al$_2$O$_3$ melts at 2345 K, while Fe$_2$O$_3$ at 1867 K.

- Strictly speaking, oxidation can happen with other gases too [since it is really defined as a loss of electrons during a reaction](https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-oxidation-in-chemistry-605456). But in burning, we are talking air and oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

To burn, a material must contain a chemical or a chemical compound which releases lots of heat when it reacts with oxygen in the air. Ashes do not.